# PHP Compare integers

Tags: php, if-statement, integer, compare

I have the following integers

```
7
77
0
20
```

in an array. I use them to check from where a call originated.
Numbers like `730010123, 772930013, 20391938.`
What I need to do is I need a way to check if the number starts with 7 or 77 for an example.


Is there any way to do this in `PHP` and avoid a thousand if statements?

One issue I am having is that if I check if the number starts with 7 the numbers that start with 77 are being called as well. Note that 7 numbers are mobile and 77 are shared cost numbers and not equal in any way so I need to separate them.

Comment: So essentially ALL numbers starting with 7 are mobile numbers, EXCEPT they start with 77, which makes them shared cost? Easy to distinguish, just add 70, 71, ... 79 numbers to your array and detect them as being mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (substr($str, 0, 1) == '7') ||{
    if (substr($str, 0, 2) == '77'){
        //starts with '77'
    } else {
        //starts with '7'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid treating it as a string is the quickest and likely the easiest way to go about it. In fact, I can't think of another way, even though I'd feel kinda dirty doing it like this.

Comment: @Anpan - It doesn't make me feel dirty at all. Dealing with them as strings is actually cleaner, because there's no mess to clean up afterward as their is when getting rid of a remainder after division.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little example with a demo array, I hope you can use it:

```
$array = array(
    7 => 'Other',
    70 => 'Fryslan!',
    20 => 'New York',
    21 => 'Dublin',
    23 => 'Amsterdam',
);

$number = 70010123;

$place = null;

foreach($array as $possibleMatch => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/^' . (string)$possibleMatch . '/', (string)$number))
        $place = $value;
}

echo $place;
```

The answer in this case is "Fryslan". You have to remember that 7 also matches in this case? So you may want to add some metric system in case of two matches.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to handle the "integer" you received as a number as being a string.

Doing so by something like this:

```
$number = 772939913;
$filter = array (
    '77' => 'type1',
    '20' => 'type2',
    '7' => 'type3',
    '0' => 'type4');
$match = null;
foreach ($filter as $key => $val){
    $comp = substr($number, 0, strlen($key));
    if ($comp == $key){
        $match = $key;
        break;
    }
}

if ($match !== null){
    echo 'the type is: ' . $filter[$match];
   //you can proceed with your task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Is this you want?

<?php

$myarray = array(730010123, 772930013, 20391938); 

foreach($myarray as $value){

    if(substr($value, 0, 2) == "77"){
        echo "Starting With 77: <br/>";
        echo $value;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    if((substr($value, 0, 1) == "7")&&(substr($value, 0, 2) != "77")){
        echo "Starting With 7: <br/>";
        echo $value;
        echo "<br>";
    }   
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for that

```
function check_digit($var) {
    return preg_match("/^(7|77|0)\d+$/");
}

$array_to_be_check = array("730010123" , "772930013", "20391938");

print_r(array_filter($array_to_be_check, "check_digit"));
```